# C# comboBox from dataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I want combobox with values from one cell datagridview. i try this, but don't work :( any ideas?

```
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: System.NullReferenceException was unhandled

Comment: To be obvious - the `rows` collection always starts at 0. So if you specify "2", it's actually the third cell.

Comment: How many columns do you have?

Answer (score 1):

The `Value` property is `null`, and throwing the exception when you call `ToString()` on it.

Check for `null` first:

```
if (row.Cells[2].Value != null)
    comboBox1.Items.Add(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
```

Alternatively, use LINQ to iterate through the rows and populate the `ComboBox`:

```
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(
    dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                 .Where(x => x.Cells[2].Value != null)
                 .Select(x => x.Cells[2].Value.ToString())
                 .ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think row.Cells[2].Value has NULL. Try
`row.Cells[1].Value`

Comment: I had same Exception when I had in my datagridview empty cells below fillable. Try to make loop with exact count of cells. Remove `foreach`

Answer (score 0):

The `row.Cells[i]` collection always starts at 0, so depending on how many columns you have, `row.Cells[2]` is actually the third column, and could be non existent. However, if that's the case, you'd like end up with a 'System.IndexOutOfRange' exception instead.

It's more likely that the cell doesn't have anything in it, or that the row doesn't even exist. Step through the debugger and see where the error is coming up.

Another, more specific way of handling this would be to specify the range by using a `for` loop instead:

```
// Rows.Count specifies the range explicitly - if you have 5 rows, 
// if i <= 5, it will loop through until it increments to 6, then stop.
for(int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows.Cells[2].Value != null)
        comboBox1.Items.Add(dataGridView1.Rows.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
}
```